# System Center Virtual Machine Manager Service Unable to start

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have install Virtual Machine Manager on windows server 2012 R2 . it installed sucessfuly but the SCVMM  service can't be started please check the following log for and the error

when i try to start SCVMM service its endup with the following error

" The System Center Virtual Machine Manager Service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.
"
Log Name:      Application
Source:        SCVMMService
Date:          11/4/2014 7:58:55 AM
Event ID:      0
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      HC**********
Description:

```
Service cannot be started. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Remoting.IndigoSerializableObject.BuildKnownAssemblyTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Remoting.IndigoSerializableObject.InitializeKnownTypesCache(List`1 assembliesToExamine)
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Engine.Remoting.IndigoServiceHost.InitializeKnownTypesCache()
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Engine.VirtualManagerService.TimeStartupMethod(String description, TimedStartupMethod methodToTime)
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Engine.VirtualManagerService.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="SCVMMService" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">0</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-04T07:58:55.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>10656</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>HC-S*********** </Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Service cannot be started. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Remoting.IndigoSerializableObject.BuildKnownAssemblyTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Remoting.IndigoSerializableObject.InitializeKnownTypesCache(List`1 assembliesToExamine)
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Engine.Remoting.IndigoServiceHost.InitializeKnownTypesCache()
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Engine.VirtualManagerService.TimeStartupMethod(String description, TimedStartupMethod methodToTime)
   at Microsoft.VirtualManager.Engine.VirtualManagerService.OnStart(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting here.

To resolve this issue, review the AD group membership for any circular references and remove them. If the circular reference is not obvious, the script below can list the nested members of a particular group.

NOTE Use Active Directory Users and Computers to determine the top most group of the group causing issues.

dsquery group -name "Group_VMMSSU" | dsget group -members -expand

I hope you have followed these steps before installing SCVMM
High Level Deployment Process:

1. In AD, create the following accounts and groups, according to your naming convention:
   •DOMAIN\scvmmsvc                 SCVMM Service Account account 
   •DOMAIN\scvmmadmin            SCVMM RunAs account for managing hosts 
   •DOMAIN\sqlsvc                        SQL service account 
   •DOMAIN\SCVMMAdmins        SCVMM Administrators security group
2. Add the “scvmmsvc” and “scvmmadmin” account to the “SCVMMAdmins” global group.
3. Add the domain user accounts for yourself and your team to the SCVMMAdmins group.

I suggest you to check this link for more details.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/kevinholman/archive/2013/10/18/scvmm-2012-r2-quickstart-deployment-guide.aspx

Girish Prajwal

Comment: Thank you so much Sir .. i have followed your instructions and also the link's instruction but endup with the following error Logon failure. Unknown user name or bad password on the HC-************ server.
Set a valid username and password and try the operation again.

Comment: Hi Rai, I suggest you to enter the complete logon id as mentioned. example@corp.com. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and couldn't find an updated answer to the problem.

In my case, I have SCVMM (server AND console) installed on the same machine (i guess this is pretty normal for a first time installation).
I had seen the system working, then I installed all updates offered from Windows Update. After reboot, my service "System Center Virtual Machine Manager" could not start.
Solution was to look in control panel: "Programs and Features". Clicking "installed updates" there was an entry for System Center Console. 
This was a rollup 10. 
I uninstalled this, now the service is able to start, and I can log on.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This KB article from Microsoft addresses the issue- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3045931

> To resolve this issue, complete the update rollup installation by installing the VMM server update package in addition to the console update. Both the VMM server and VMM Admin Console updates must be at compatible version levels. This will typically be the same update rollup level. For example, a VMM Admin Console should be at the VMM UR5 level if the server is also at UR5.
>
> In some instances, there may not be a comparable update for a component. In that case, the component should be updated to the most recent applicable update. For example, if the VMM server is updated to a post-UR5 hotfix, but there is no corresponding hotfix for the VMM Admin Console, the VMM Admin Console should be updated to UR5.

In my case update rollup 11 was the cause for the break. Going in to **Programs and Features** -> **Installed Updates**, I noticed that Update rollup 11 for the admin console had installed successfully but Update rollup 11 for the VMM service had failed.

I manually installed the failed update (in my case http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/5/1/7515E3DB-1B43-4E7F-8774-A877CCEAA96E/kb3184831_vmmserver_amd64.msp) and now VMM service is able to start and stay started.